# How do I build a better blog website?

Tags: technical-writing, blog

I've spent the last few days building a website that I want to use a showcase for my written work, and as a personal blog. What fundamental changes should I make to improve a viewer's experience? 
The site is [AcfWorks.com](http://www.acfworks.com)

Comment: This is pretty broad as written, and sounds like you're asking for a critique of your blog.  Could you please [edit] to describe what you've done and what you think could be improved about it?  Try to be more specific -- are your questions about styling, tagging, length of posts, how you manage comments, promotion, or what?  I'm putting this on hold for now; after you edit it will go into a review queue for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose a definite goal for your site. What do you want users to do? Look around, subscribe to an email list, join you on Facebook?
2. Cut down on extras that take away from your main goal. For example, the large image at the top of each page. Looks nice, doesn't tell the story.
3. Be more clear about what everything is. Did you write the content for these projects?
   For example: Commercial Writing Examples

Comment: Totally agree. Icouldn't discern what the page is about. The images have no message.

Comment: Thank you! I away the "written works" section for now, made the header images a lot smaller, and tried to make the homepage a bit clearer. What do you think?